# Find Missing Value in Changing Range of Numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to find missing or 'skipped' values in my table. Here is an example of my table.

```
| Country      | U  | Date     |
| USA          | 1  | 1/1/2015 |
| USA          | 2  | 2/1/2015 |
| USA          | 3  | 3/1/2015 |
| USA          | 5  | 5/1/2015 |
| USA          | 6  | 6/1/2015 |
| USA          | 7  | 7/1/2015 |
| USA          | 8  | 8/1/2015 |
| USA          | 9  | 9/1/2015 |
| Germany      | 2  | 4/1/2015 |
| Germany      | 3  | 5/1/2015 |
| Germany      | 4  | 6/1/2015 |
| Germany      | 5  | 7/1/2015 |
| Germany      | 6  | 8/1/2015 |
| Germany      | 7  | 9/1/2015 |
| Canada       | 1  | 3/1/2015 |
| Canada       | 2  | 4/1/2015 |
| Canada       | 3  | 6/1/2015 |
| Canada       | 4  | 7/1/2015 |
```

There's a couple things I need to find which would probably result in two different queries, which is ok.

Firstly when grouped by Country and filtered by USA you find the U column goes from 1-9 but is missing U = 4 as well as the month corresponding to that row of 4/1/2015.

Secondly when grouped by country and filtered by Germany you find the U column is missing the first record where U = 1 and it's corresponding date being 3/1/2015.

And then lastly when grouped by country and filtered by Canada you find the U column has sequential ordering however the Date column is missing a month - 5/1/2015.

I've tried `LAG()` and `LEAD()` methods but that doesn't seem to work because I can't aggregate `U`. Has anyone a solution to this problem?

Comment: what is the maximum `U` you can have?

Comment: So what are your expected results?You cant return values which dont exist

Comment: @vkp the max U would be 9. The max Date would be today's Month.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use cte's to construct the numbers and dates table and then `left join` the main table to find the missing records.

```
with nums as (select 1 as num union all select 2 union all ... select 9)
, dates as (select '01/01/2015' as dt union all select '02/01/2015'..
            select '12/01/2015')
select n.num, t.country, d.dt
from nums n
left join tablename t on n.num = t.U
left join dates d on d.dt = t.date
where t.U is null or t.date is null
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are simply trying to find the missing months, and that `U` can be ignored except when it starts with an integer greater than `1`, in which case you need to use `U` to find this missing dates that would have existed if `U` had started at `1`.

If you need to find the missing numbers in `U`, this will have to be adapted since it merely focuses on missing dates.

Given the data:

```
declare @data table (Country varchar(10), U int, [Date] date)

insert into @data values
('USA', 1, '1/1/2015'),
('USA', 2, '2/1/2015'),
('USA', 3, '3/1/2015'),
('USA', 5, '5/1/2015'),
('USA', 6, '6/1/2015'),
('USA', 7, '7/1/2015'),
('USA', 8, '8/1/2015'),
('USA', 9, '9/1/2015'),
('Germany', 2, '4/1/2015'),
('Germany', 3, '5/1/2015'),
('Germany', 4, '6/1/2015'),
('Germany', 5, '7/1/2015'),
('Germany', 6, '8/1/2015'),
('Germany', 7, '9/1/2015'),
('Canada', 1, '3/1/2015'),
('Canada', 2, '4/1/2015'),
('Canada', 3, '6/1/2015'),
('Canada', 4, '7/1/2015')
```

You can use two queries to build a list of `min` and `max` dates for each country, and then build a complete list of dates that should exist for each country.

```
select Country, dateadd(month, (-1 * min(U)) + 1, min([Date])) as min_Date, max([Date]) as max_Date
into   #min_max
from   @data
group by Country

;with cte (Country, [Date]) as (
  select Country, min_Date from #min_max
  union all
  select cte.Country, dateadd(month, 1, cte.Date) from #min_max t inner join cte on t.Country = cte.Country where cte.[Date] < t.max_Date
)
select *
into   #ranges
from   cte
```

If we inspect the data in `#min_max` and `#ranges`, you will see the following:

```
select * from #min_max

Country    min_Date   max_Date
---------- ---------- ----------
Canada     2015-03-01 2015-07-01
Germany    2015-03-01 2015-09-01
USA        2015-01-01 2015-09-01

select * from #ranges order by 1, 2

Country    Date
---------- ----------
Canada     2015-03-01
Canada     2015-04-01
Canada     2015-05-01
Canada     2015-06-01
Canada     2015-07-01
Germany    2015-03-01
Germany    2015-04-01
Germany    2015-05-01
Germany    2015-06-01
Germany    2015-07-01
Germany    2015-08-01
Germany    2015-09-01
USA        2015-01-01
USA        2015-02-01
USA        2015-03-01
USA        2015-04-01
USA        2015-05-01
USA        2015-06-01
USA        2015-07-01
USA        2015-08-01
USA        2015-09-01
```

Then it is simple to find the records in `#ranges` that don't exist in your original data:

```
select *
from   #ranges r
where  not exists (
         select 1
         from   @data d
         where  r.Country = d.Country
           and  r.[Date] = d.[Date]
       )

Country    Date
---------- ----------
Germany    2015-03-01
USA        2015-04-01
Canada     2015-05-01
```

Then we drop our temp tables:

```
drop table #min_max, #ranges
```